# What is the best way to produce large results in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, azure-hdinsight

I've been trying to run some Hive queries with largish result sets. My normal approach is to submit a job through the WebHCat API, and read the results from the resulting stdout file, or to just run hive at the console and pipe stdout to a file. However, with large results (more than one reducer used), the stdout is blank or truncated.

My current solution is to create a new table from the results `CREATE TABLE FROM SELECT` which introduces an extra step, and leaves the table to clear up afterwards if I don't want to keep the result set.

Does anyone have a better method for capturing all the results from such a Hive query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the data directly to a directory on either hdfs or the local file system, then do what you want with the files. For example, to generate CSV files:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY '/hive/output/folder'
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
STORED AS TEXTFILE
SELECT ... FROM ...;
```

This is essentially the same as `CREATE TABLE FROM SELECT` but you don't have to clean up the table. Here's the full documentation:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-Writingdataintothefilesystemfromqueries